# export Key or Index out of JQuery .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, indexing, key

My `.each` loop does not return a variable which has to be accessible from outside the loop.

here's the code:

```
  $.each($("#recipients .address"), function(i, o) {
     
    var new_recipients_count = (i + 1);
 
  });

var placeholder_count = new_recipients_count;
  
  var newRow = '<input type="text" name="Email_Address" placeholder="  ' + placeholder_count + ' ">';

I'm a novice regarding Jquery, 99 % of this code is from code examples copy/paste and I'm amazed that it almost works perfectly as I need it, but I dont know how to expórt a the ibdex fromthe `.each` loop which needs to be printed in a fields placeholder.
```

Comment: `##recipients` is a typo, it should just have one `#`.

Comment: You never do anything with `newRow`.

Comment: The return value of the `.each()` callback function is only used to determine if the loop should continue; if it returns `false`, the loop stops.

Comment: It seems like `new_reipients_count` is the same as `$("#recipients .address").length`. Why do you think you need to assign it inside the loop?

Comment: If you want to assign `new_recipients_count` inside the loop, don't redeclare it with `var`. That declares a new variable that's local to the callback function.